# How to convert Response type to suitable format for Html file?

Tags: python, json, api, flask, flask-restful

I am writing a method in flask app. I `get` data from `http://localhost:5000/product` and return response as `text` . code of this method is:

```
import requests


@app.route('/product')
def product():
    info = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/product') 
    return info.text
```

output of this method is:

```
[ { "P_ID": 1, "active": true, "count": 100, "price": 1000, "title": "product1" },
  { "P_ID": 2, "active": false, "count": 12, "price": 2500, "title": "Product2" } ]
```

Now, I want to use these data in `html` file. I have a table in `html` file with columns `P_ID`,`title`,`count`,`price` and `active`.I want to put these data to this table but I don't know how do I it. I changed this method as below but it don't work correctly.

When I run using `python app.py` , I see integer numbers in columns of table but I wouldn't see information of `info` in table. When I use `product.title` or `product["title"]` in `product.html`file, I will see `<built-in method title of str object at 0x018311C0>` in title column of table.

```
import requests
from flask import render_template


@app.route('/product')
def product():
    info = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/product') 
    info = info.text
    return render_template('product.html', info=info)
```

`product.html` file is:

```
{% block body %}
<body>
<h1>Products List</h1>

<table  style="text-align: center" width="15%" border="3px" bgcolor="#FFE4E1">
    <tr><td><a href='/add'>Add New Product</a></td></tr>
</table>
<br><br>
<table style="text-align: center" width="50%" align="left" border= "3px solid black" border- 
collapse= collapse bgcolor="#E0FFFF">
    <tr>
        <th> ID </th>
        <th> Title </th>
        <th> Count </th>
        <th> Price </th>
        <th> Active </th>
        <th> Actions </th>
   </tr>
    {% for product in info %}
   <tr>
        <td> {{product[0]}} </td>
        <td> {{product[1]}} </td>
        <td> {{product[2]}} </td>
        <td> {{product[3]}} </td>
        <td> {{product[4]}} </td>
        <td> <a href='/edit/{{product[0]}}'>Edit</a> 
        <a href='/delete/{{product[0]}}' onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure To Delete?')">Delete</a> </td>

     </tr>
    {% endfor %}
 </table>
 </body>
 {% endblock %}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: you have dictionaries so use `product["P_ID"]` or `product.P_ID` instead of `product[0]`

Comment: what means `don't work correctly.` If you get error then show it in question (not commmet) as text (not image). Always show FULL error - it is very important information. We can't read in your mind. And don't expect that we will run code to see error.

Comment: BTW: if page sends JSON data then get it as `info.json()` instead of `info.text`

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem solved with your guidance.